# The constructor PluginProtos.CodeGeneratorResponse.File(String) is undefined

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-mvc

i have an error when i try to create "File fileSave = new File()" I get the error:
"The PluginProtos.CodeGeneratorResponse.File(String) constructor is undefined". please help me:

this is my code:

```
    public String UpLoadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
        String PathToProducts = servletContext.getRealPath("/resources/Image/products/");
        Iterator<String> imageName = request.getFileNames();
        MultipartFile imageFile =request.getFile(imageName.next());
        
        File fileSave = new File(PathToProducts + imageFile.getOriginalFilename());
        
        
        return"";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error stack message , there are may be some potential issues

- pls ensure class `File`  which in your code snippet is localated at  package path `java.io`, Noticed that the message `The PluginProtos.CodeGeneratorResponse.File(String)` , it seems like you had been a wrong way in import `File` package .
- Checkout the `File path`,make sure the path `PathToProducts + imageFile.getOriginalFilename()` is available ;

Provided more infomation or minimum operational demo will be more efficient and accurate  for yout issue!